# filling 2d array compiler telling me i'm referencing an object that doesn't exist

Tags: c#

I can't figure out why it's telling me the object is null when I'm trying to fill the array with an object that I'm constructing.

```
public int size;
// Use this for initialization
public void Start()
{
    size = 10;
    Unit[,] array = new Unit[size,size];
    int i, j;
    for(i = 1; i<=size; i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            if(i>=1&&j>=1)
            {
                array[i, j] = new Unit(array[i - 1, j].getHeight(), array[i, j - 1].getHeight());
            }
            else if(i>=1)
            {
                array[i, j] = new Unit(array[i - 1, j].getHeight(), 0);
            }
            else
            {
                array[i, j] = new Unit(0, 0);
            }
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= size; j++)
        {
            Debug.Log(array[i,j].getHeight());
        }
    }
}
```

the Objects I am creating come from a constructor; Unit(int,int)
It says line 23. I'm assuming that it means that the object doesn't exist in the the array but i'm creating the object so IDK

Comment: This line `for(i = 1; i<=size; i++)` should be ` for(i = 0; i<size; i++)` as C# is base 0

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Always always always fee the actual error message to Google first.

Answer (score 0):

Two erros that I see, the first is that the first for loop should be `for(i = 0; i<size; i++)` as c# is base 0. This would give you the null object because when you try to assign

```
if(i>=1&&j>=1)
{
    array[i, j] = new Unit(array[i - 1, j].getHeight(), array[i, j - 1].getHeight());
}
```

when i=1, `array[0,j]` was never assign (since i started in 1), so it's value is null.

The other is in the last group of loops, as the conditions should be the following:

```
for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < size; j++)
    {
        Debug.Log(array[i,j].getHeight());
    }
}
```

Because since C# is base 0, the indexes goes from `0` to `size-1`